# PySDL2: Renderer or Window Surface for handling colors and text?

Tags: window, renderer, pysdl2

My question concerns the `sdl2.ext.Renderer` mainly, and has to do with a problem I've encountered when trying to render sprites on a `sdl2.ext.Window` surface.

So right now, for coloring my background on an SDL2 Window, I make the following call:

```
White = sdl2.ext.Color(255,255,255)

    class Background(sdl2.ext.SoftwareSpriteRenderSystem):
        def __init__(self,window):
            super(Background,self).__init__(window)
            sdl2.ext.fill(self.surface,White)
```

This colors the surface of the Window with a white background. However, I also want to display text on the screen. This is done by creating a `TextureSprite` using the `from_text` method of the `sdl2.ext.SpriteFactory` class as follows:

```
Renderer = sdl2.ext.Renderer(W) # Creating Renderer

ManagerFont = sdl2.ext.FontManager(font_path = "OpenSans.ttf", size = 14) # Creating Font Manager

Factory = sdl2.ext.SpriteFactory(renderer=Renderer) # Creating Sprite Factory

Text = Factory.from_text("Unisung Softworks",fontmanager=ManagerFont) # Creating TextureSprite from Text

Renderer.copy(Text, dstrect= (0,0,Text.size[0],Text.size[1])) # Resizing the Texture to fit the text dimensions when rendered
```

The problem occurs when the event loop is run.

```
 running = True
    while running:
        events = sdl2.ext.get_events()
        for event in events:
            if event.type == sdl2.SDL_QUIT:
                running = False
                break
            if event.type == sdl2.SDL_MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                pass

        Renderer.copy(Text, dstrect= (0,0,Text.size[0],Text.size[1]))
        Renderer.present() # Problem 1
        W.refresh() # Problem 2
    return 0
```

[**Full Example Paste**](http://pastebin.com/GXLyDfdm)

When both Renderer.present() and W.refresh() are called, I get a flickering effect from the screen. **This seems to be because the Renderer overwrites the White colored Window surface, which then gets colored over again by the Window.refresh() call.** This then repeats, resulting in a flickering mess.

I would like to know what I can do to solve this problem? Should I even be using both Window.refresh() and the Renderer at the same time? Is there a way to let one render the other? (Renderer renders background for example). If anyone can help me out, that would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are using `Window.refresh()` along with a `SDL_Renderer` and a `SoftwareSpriteSystem` with `SDL_Texture` objects.

As outlined in the PySDL2 docs, this is likely to break (since software surface buffers get mixed with hardware-based textures) and you should avoid it. If you want to color the window background, you should use `Renderer.clear(White)` instead of your `Background` class and call it before copying the text via `Renderer.copy()`:

```
Renderer.clear(White)
Renderer.copy(Text, dstrect= (0,0,Text.size[0],Text.size[1]))
Renderer.present()
```

Do not forget to change the color for your `FontManager`. By default it uses a white text color, so you should change it to e.g. your `Red` color:

```
ManagerFont = sdl2.ext.FontManager(font_path = "OpenSans.ttf", size = 14, color=Red)
```

Comment: Thanks Marcus. I can also use the Renderer to Draw rectangles and fill colors which were previously done via sdl2.ext.fill. (In some of my other files). This simplifies things a whole bunch.

Comment: For low-level primitives, I also recommend you to take a look at the `sdlgfx` module, which wraps SDL2_gfx, an excellent library for 2D primitives.